# How to run a react project?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to run a react project cloned from **Github** that works with `NodeJs`. In the `.readme` file, the dev tells that i just need to run `npm start` in backend folder, then on frontend folder.

The problem is that I'm receiving errors:

In backend folder:

```
$ npm start

> backend@1.0.0 start
> nodemon server.js  

[nodemon] 2.0.20
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:959
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'nodemailer'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\alexia.borelvaéhotma\Desktop\stage\Site-centre-formation\backend\utils\emailSend.js
- C:\Users\alexia.borelvaéhotma\Desktop\stage\Site-centre-formation\backend\controllers\user.controllers.js
- C:\Users\alexia.borelvaéhotma\Desktop\stage\Site-centre-formation\backend\routes\userapi.js
- C:\Users\alexia.borelvaéhotma\Desktop\stage\Site-centre-formation\backend\server.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:956:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:804:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\alexia.borelvaéhotma\Desktop\stage\Site-centre-formation\backend\utils\emailSend.js:1:20)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\alexia.borelvaéhotma\\Desktop\\stage\\Site-centre-formation\\backend\\utils\\emailSend.js',
    'C:\\Users\\alexia.borelvaéhotma\\Desktop\\stage\\Site-centre-formation\\backend\\controllers\\user.controllers.js',                                                                      ailSend.js',
    'C:\\Users\\alexia.borelvaéhotma\\Desktop\\stage\\Site-centre-formation\\backend\\routes\\urs\\user.controllers.jsserapi.js',
    'C:\\Users\\alexia.borelvaéhotma\\Desktop\\stage\\Site-centre-formation\\backend\\server.jsserapi.js','                                                                                              '
  ]
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

In frontend folder:

```
$ npm start

> frontend@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

'react-scripts' n’est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes.
```

Any idea? thanks for your answer.

I've tried `npm install` in the front folder, but it doesn't work:

```
$ cd formation-frontend/

alexia.borelvaéhotma@AlexiaMac8 MINGW64 ~/Desktop/stage/Site-centre-formation/formation-frontend (main)
$ npm install
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: react-typical@0.1.3
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0-rc.1" from @react-aria/ssr@3.1.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-aria/ssr
npm ERR!     @react-aria/ssr@"^3.0.1" from @restart/ui@0.2.6
npm ERR!     node_modules/@restart/ui
npm ERR!       @restart/ui@"^0.2.5" from react-bootstrap@2.1.1
npm ERR!       node_modules/react-bootstrap
npm ERR!         react-bootstrap@"^2.0.3" from the root project
npm ERR!   21 more (@restart/hooks, @restart/ui, @testing-library/react, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from react-typical@0.1.3
npm ERR! node_modules/react-typical
npm ERR!   react-typical@"^0.1.3" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from react-typical@0.1.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-typical
npm ERR!     react-typical@"^0.1.3" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\alexia.borelvaéhotma\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-11-21T09_06_44_713Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\alexia.borelvaéhotma\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-11-21T09_06_44_713Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: have you checked your node-version vs repo's node version (or react version)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the dependencies first with `npm install`, since the dependencies normally won't be upload to GitHub.
Then run `rpm start` again. Be aware the repository you run these commands matter as well.

Comment: npm install doesn't works:

Comment: $ npm install
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

Comment: @Lexy712 ```npm install --legacy-peer-deps``` is a safer option, try this first.

Comment: thank you very much! it helps me resolve problems due to wrong directory :)

Comment: @Lexy712 If you find my answer useful, please mark it as accepted answer and upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you've not dependencies for the current project, in your console go to the root directory of your project then type this.

```bash
    npm install
    npm start
```

Comment: thank you. I did so, but it seams like a file is missing:

Comment: npm install
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\alexia.borelvaéhotma\Desktop\stage\Site-centre-formation/package.json   
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\alexia.borelvaéhotma\Desktop\stage\Site-centre-formation\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\alexia.borelvaéhotma\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-11-21T09_32_04_548Z-debug-0.log

Comment: finally I managed to make an "npm start" on my backend folder. it perfectly listening at the right port. 
thank you very much for your help! 

unfortunately, i still having problems running the front folder... the console says that it can't find 'react' module. 

$ npm start

> frontend@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:959
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'react'